# Google App Engine Blobs

Tags: google-app-engine

If I am right, using the Blobstore API (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Blobstore) requires apps to have billing enabled. However, do application need to have billing enabled to use db.BlobProperty() ?
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#Blob

If I understand this correctly, then I only need billing enabled when using the Blobstore, but I can store binary data with BlobProperty() without having to use the Blobstore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use BlobProperty without having billing enabled. But note that BlobProperty can store much smaller amounts than the Blobstore.